# cycle as backgound image is NOT working

Tags: jquery, css, image, fullscreen, stretch

I'm trying to cycle images as ***background image*** and it's not working.

I know how to make that slider with img tag inside the li tag but it ***must*** stay on that format as background image

The Html:

```
<ul>
    <li id="img1"></li>
    <li id="img2"></li>
    <li id="img3"></li>
    <li id="img4"></li>
</ul>


<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>$('li').cycle();</script>
```

the CSS :

```
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px black solid;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#img1 {
    background-image : url('http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/upictures/205882.gif');
}

#img2 {
    background-image : url('http://media.merchantcircle.com/20649169/Husky-Logo-100x100_full.gif');
}

#img3 {
    background-image : url('http://www.wolfontheloose.com/assets/images/BioHazard_100x100_.jpg');
}

#img4 {
    background-image : url('http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/games_225/worms_261/worms_firearms_avatar_100x100_69290.jpg');
}
```

the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fj5V3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for the parent element. Call like this

```
$('ul').cycle();
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fj5V3/2/)